# How to use Local as integer or string for bool in ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net, loops, local

Before I save data to database I whant to check one more condition on my cotext that would be saved:

```
var numberOfChanges = dbContext.CustomerTables.Local;
```

Now this works, "numberOfChanges" is returnig me a number of changes - count, that will be changed in my Table - Customer Table.

But If I whant to use "numberOfChanges in my bool:

```
dbContext.UsersTables.Add(userModel.User);

var role= (userModel.User.Roles).ToString();

var numberOfChanges = dbContext.CustomerTables.Local;

if (role == "1" || role == "2" && numberOfChanges != 0)
{
   ModelState.AddModelError("UsernameAdvance", "");
}
else
{
  dbContext.SaveChanges();
  TempData["UserSuccess"] = "ste dodali novega uporabnika!";
  return new ContentResult() { Content = "success" };
                                    }
```

In this case error is shown: "cannot apply operator to operands of type int", any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Why do you use `var` at all? That doesn't help us to understand your question.

Comment: because it says that I cannot convert it to int or string. "Cannot convert source type ... table name ... to type string.

Comment: If you hold the mouse over `Local`, what does intellisense tell you? What is _it_?

Comment: System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection

Comment: An `ObservableCollection` is a collection. That means it is not a single object but probably multiple. That's the reason why you can't assign it to a single `int` or `string` variable. _"But If I whant to use "numberOfChanges in my loop"_ We can't help you further if you don't show what you're actually trying to do in the loop or what you're looping at all.

Comment: I update my code. I whant to do simple condition, where I check if there is something in "numberOfChanges" if not, save, if there is something do Message

Comment: sorry by later, I typed in my question, I write "loop" instead "bool"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I update my code. I whant to do simple condition, where I check if
>   there is something in "numberOfChanges" if not, save, if there is
>   something do Message

Since `numberOfChanges` is an `ObservableCollection<T>` you can use `Any`:

```
bool hasChanges = numberOfChanges.Any();
if (role == "1" || (role == "2" && hasChanges))
{
   // ...
}
else
{
   // ...
}
```